# Find tables in oracle that dont have composite primary key using DatabaseMetaData Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
String [] tableTypes = { "TABLE" };
    DatabaseMetaData md = (DatabaseMetaData) dbConnection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", tableTypes);
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
    }
```

Im using this part of the code to get all tables from my local oracle database but I need to change it in order to get back only the tablet that have only one primary key. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a trick question: there can either be one primary key or none.  Anything else is a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or index.

Comment: You cannot have more than one primary key constraint defined on a table. Maybe you meant tables with single-column(there can be a composite one) primary key?

Comment: If a table has 2 primary keys i want this table to now show up but if a table has only 1, I want that table. The thing is that I dont have any idea how to implement that in java!

Comment: Listen carefully: there is no such thing as a table with 2 primary keys. Either a table has *one* primary key, or it doesn't have a primary key at all.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I can have "two" primary keys, for example --> primary key(name, surname)

Comment: It's called composite primary key. You still have ONE primary key constraint.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov yeah sorry about that you are right, but do u get the idea of what I need to do?

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation of `DatabaseMetaData` to see if it has any methods that might help you get the information you need?

Comment: getTables() will **not** return that information. You will need to use `getPrimaryKeys()` for each table and see how many columns it returns: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
static Statement statement = null;
static ResultSet result = null;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {

        Class.forName(driverClassName);
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, passwd);

        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        String[] tableTypes = {"TABLE"};
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd;
        dbmd = dbConnection.getMetaData();

        result = dbmd.getTables("%", username, "%", new String[]{tableTypes[0]});
        while (result.next()) {
            String tableName = result.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            ResultSet tempSet = dbmd.getPrimaryKeys(null, username, tableName);

            String keyName="";
            int counter=0;
            while (tempSet.next()) {
                keyName = tempSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                counter++;

            }
            if(counter == 1) {
                System.out.println(tableName);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use [`DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for each table in that loop:

```
String [] tableTypes = { "TABLE" };
DatabaseMetaData md = dbConnection.getMetaData(); // the cast is unnecessary!
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", tableTypes);
while (rs.next()) 
{
  String schema = rs.getString(2);
  String table = rs.getString(3);
  ResultSet pkRs = md.getPrimaryKeys(null, schema, table);
  int colCount = 0;
  while (pkRs.next()) 
  {
     colCount ++;
  }
  pkRs.close();
  if (colCount = 1) 
  {
      System.out.println("Table " + table + " has a single column primary key");
  }
}
```

However, this will be **awfully** slow. Using a query that retrieves this information directly from `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns` is going to be a **lot** faster:

```
select col.table_name, count(*)
from user_constraints uc
  join user_cons_columns col 
    on col.table_name = uc.table_name 
   and col.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
where constraint_type = 'P'
group by col.table_name 
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Table can have up to one primary key. This primary can be compound - i.e. consisting of multiple columns. The other (2nd) key might be UNIQUE (+ not NULL) which is not exactly the same as primary.

Best way how to check columns is to query ALL_CONTRAINTS view. JDBC method DatabaseMetaData has only limited functionality.